# What is the technology used to build u-blox's u-center?

Tags: gps

u-blox's u-center is a desktop application for Windows OS that is light-weight and accommodates all the streamed data without problems.

What is the toolkit or framework (.Net "I doubt it", Win32 API, MFC) used to build such a desktop application like u-blox's u-center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based on Win32 API and MFC. MFC is statically linked. See also the second page of the user manual.

https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/u-Center_UserGuide_%28UBX-13005250%29.pdf